# Finding the first non-null in a partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, coalesce

I am using SQL Server. I have a database which has a person and year (the combination creates uniqueness) where another column (we'll call it married status) has null values. I want to impute these nulls. I figure that since this column usually doesn't change often, I will take the next non-null value for that person, or if it's at the end of the data, the previous non-null value. For instance:

| Person | Year | MaritalStatus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Moe | 2001 | NULL |
| Moe | 2002 | NULL |
| Moe | 2003 | Married |
| Larry | 2001 | Single |
| Larry | 2002 | NULL |
| Larry | 2003 | NULL |
| Curly | 2001 | Single |
| Curly | 2002 | NULL |
| Curly | 2003 | Married |

Moe's nulls should be changed to Married, Larry's nulls should be changed to single, and Curly's null should be changed to Married.

My thought was to use coalesce with over like so (with similar logic to choose preceding nulls):

```
select
    Person,
    Year,
    coalesce(MaritalStatus) over (partition by Person order by Year rows between current row and unbounded following)
from mytable
```

It appears over doesn't work with `coalesce`. Is there some easy way to do this without CTE's or subqueries (I'm trying to avoid this if possible as it will make it a little harder to understand for the next person).

Edit:
Based on Tim's answer I think I have something:

```
cte AS (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (PARTITION BY Person,
            CASE WHEN MaritalStatus IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
            ORDER BY Year DESC) rn
    FROM mytable
),

cte2 as (
SELECT 
    t1.Person,
    t1.Year,
    max(t2.rn) as maxrn,
    min(t3.rn) as minrn
FROM mytable t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2
    ON t2.Person = t1.Person AND
       t2.MaritalStatus IS NOT NULL and
       t1.year<t2.year
LEFT JOIN cte t3
    ON t3.Person = t1.Person AND
       t3.MaritalStatus IS NOT NULL and
       t1.year>t3.year
group by t1.Person,t1.Year
),

cte3 as(
    select
        t1.person,
        t1.year,
        coalesce(t1.maritalstatus,t4.maritalstatus,t3.maritalstatus) as maritalstatus
    from mytable t1
        left join cte2 t2
            on t1.person=t2.person and
            t1.year=t2.year
        left join cte t3
            on t1.person=t3.person and
            t3.maritalstatus is not null and
            t2.maxrn=t3.rn
        left join cte t4
            on t1.person=t4.person and
            t4.maritalstatus is not null and
            t2.minrn=t4.rn
            
)
select * from cte3
```

Comment: Do we take the _earlier_ most recent non `NULL` value or the _later_ non `NULL` value?  Your update logic is not entirely clear.

Comment: Later if possible (if there's no non-nulls that are later, then earlier). Right now I'm just trying to get the logic for the Later non-nulls first.

Comment: CTE's & sub-queries are basic tools every SQL developer should know how to use. Trying to avoid them is a bad idea.

Comment: I guess I'm not against ctes or subqueries. As long they're not clunky, which is what all of my solutions were looking like)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could try the following approach.  Here we are applying `ROW_NUMBER` with a partition on person and *also* a partition on whether or not the marital status value is `NULL`.  We then use the most recent non `NULL` marital status value, per person, to fill in any `NULL` missing marital status values.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                  PARTITION BY Person,
                               CASE WHEN MaritalStatus IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                  ORDER BY Year DESC) rn
    FROM mytable
)

SELECT t1.Person, t1.Year, COALESCE(t1.MaritalStatus, t2.MaritalStatus) AS MaritalStatus
FROM mytable t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2
    ON t2.Person = t1.Person AND
       t2.MaritalStatus IS NOT NULL AND
       t2.rn = 1;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: This gets us somewhere. The problem is that it takes the last non-null value, not the next. For instance if there were 2 more rows for curly where 2004 he has a null value and 2005 he is divorced, this will replace both nulls with divorced (Single->Divorced->Married->Divorced->Divorced) when I want to replace the first null with married and the second null with divorced (Single->Married->Married->Divorced->Divorced)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using only window functions.  The key idea is to get the first year where there is a marital status.  Then spread the marital status from that year on all rows:

```
SELECT t.*,
       MAX(CASE WHEN year = first_year_ms THEN MaritalStatus END) OVER (PARTITION BY person) as first_marital_status
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             MIN(CASE WHEN MaritalStatus IS NOT NULL THEN year END) OVER (PARTITION BY person) as first_year_ms
      FROM t
     ) t
ORDER BY person, year;
```

An even simpler method might be to use a lateral join:

```
select *
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.maritalstatus
      from t t2
      where t2.person = t.person and t2.maritalstatus is not null
      order by t2.year asc
     ) t2;
```

With an index on `(person, maritalstatus, year)`, this might be the fastest approach.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1e331dfac456d3ba93dd54eac5de2b15) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

You can still do this with window functions:

```
SELECT t.*,
       COALESCE(MAX(MaritalStatus) OVER (PARTITION BY person, grp_after),
                MAX(MaritalStatus) OVER (PARTITION BY person, grp_before)
               ) as next_marital_status
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             COUNT(MaritalStatus) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY year DESC) as grp_after,
             COUNT(MaritalStatus) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY year ASC) as grp_before
      FROM t
     ) t
ORDER BY person, year;
```

Or using `apply`:

```
select *
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.maritalstatus
      from t t2
      where t2.person = t.person and t2.maritalstatus is not null
      order by (case when t2.year >= t.year then 1 else 2 end),
               (case when t2.year >= t.year then t2.year end) asc,
               t2.year desc
     ) t2
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f95c68a7b391f565d1c3bc33bcf0810a) is SQL Fiddle for this.

Comment: This has the same downside as Tim's answer. It takes the first/last non-null rather the next non-null (see my comment above)

Comment: @NosonDaitchman . . . You can still use window functions or `apply`.  The code is a wee bit more complicated because of the default if no value is present.  I think I confused myself looking at Tim's answer.